# Waiting for the node to be synchronized with its peers

Tags: baker, xtz

I'm new to Tezos Baking and just setup my node on my laptop to get used the system. My node appears to be fully synchronized with current time stamps. Now when I run the command to start the baker I get "Waiting for the node to be synchronized with its peers..." and it hangs like this. I'm assuming this is because I currently don't have any Tezos in my baker wallet, would this be the case? or would the baker still start? I don't want to transfer the Tezos until I'm sure everything is running fine.

Also can anyone tell me how much the hardware effects the performance of the node and ultimately the profitability? I understand a fast storage device such as SSD is best but what about processor etc? I see many people use RPi, are these sufficient or will better hardware yield better performance?

Thanks

Comment: please offer more technical details so we can assist you here. Otherwise if you need more dynamic assistance please go to community channels like telegram or riot.

Answer (score 3):

You only need the equivalent of 2 CPU cores to bake/endorse with Tezos, and about 4 GB of RAM. Any more will remain idle. Yes, SSD due to poor database implementation, unfortunately.

You should run this command before starting the baker and endorser: `export TEZOS_LOG='* -> debug'`

That will give you much more output so you have an idea of what is happening. If the baker/endorser say you need to wait to sync, then you need to wait and sync. Did you import a snapshot? If not, it'll take a good 2-4 days to sync.

You need to transfer your tokens now to your baking address and register it now if you want to bake. There is a mandatory waiting period of approx 30 days before you'll begin to bake. The longer you wait to transfer/activate, the longer it'll be before you actually start.

Comment: I tried to install a snapshot but it kept failing saying somethings along the line of the file is inconsistent.

Comment: Do the tokens just need to be in my baker wallet on my ledger for this long or I need my node ruining and fully setup with with my baking key?

Comment: You need your node up and sync'd so that you can inject the operation that says "I want to be a baker". On the next block # which is a multiple of 512, a snapshot will be taken of the whole network. If your tokens are not present in the address, they will not get counted and the network might believe you are trying to bake with 0 funds.

Comment: In ledger I have two apps, the Tezos one that holds my tokens, and the tezos baking app. Do I hold my funds in the regular tezos app or do I need to transfer to the address fro the baking? I assume the latter but if I do that I can't see any way to get the funds back out should I wish as there is no account in ledger live.

Comment: @StevenRichards You need to have funds in your baking address in order to pay the bonds for any blocks and endorsements you create. Additionally, the baking app on your ledger must be active when it is your turn, otherwise you cannot sign and you'll lose the rewards.

Comment: I just tried to transfer the funds to the address provided by the baking app and the it said its the same address? so it appears the Tezos wallet is linked to the app? and not a separate wallet? I though the app was a separate wallet and I couldn't see a way to get funds out if I transferred to the address.

Comment: @StevenRichards It is a separate app, but the baking app only signs new blocks and endorsements when it is your turn. Thus, the baking app must be frontmost app on your ledger when it is your turn, otherwise you will miss.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my node is now synchronized and when I run command  './tezos-client -A get balance for NAME' it correctly shows my balance. Do I just is this all I need to do? and now simply wait the 30 day until I can start baking? Is there any checks I can make to ensure everything is setup correctly while I'm waiting?

Comment: Did you register yourself as baker? You must do this, otherwise, how does the chain know you are different than any other address? `tezos-client register key NAME as delegate` It's a 7 cycle waiting period, after the current cycle ends before you are granted any rights. A cycle is 4096 blocks; 1 block is 60s. In a couple cycles, look on tzstats.com to check if it sees you as a 'Baker account'. Make sure you have -baker and -endorser both running plus the node at all times. Join the baker's slack channel.

Comment: I just checked that link and it showed 'basic' account, I had previously run the command to delegate, however decided to run it again, my account then immediately changed to 'Baker Account revealed'. Will I have to wait 7 cycles from now or will it be from the shown creation date which is the 18th and was when my funds were transferred in.

Comment: Probably have to wait 7 cycles from when the command to activate was seen by the chain.